# Desktop machine freezes during boot and during several reboots until it "warms up"

Tags: boot, graphics-card, freeze, nvidia-graphics-card

I've had this desktop computer for nearly 2 years and it runs fine most of the time. But when it's been off for a while and is turned back on it regularly freezes a different stages of booting. Sometimes it freezes at the BIOS boot screen. Other times it makes it all the way to the graphical desktop. But it typically takes half a dozen attempts until it's fully operational.

On rare occasions there is a clear video card failure. It's obvious because the screen will suddenly change colors or display random noise. The video card is an Nvidia GTX 760.

I'm not sure if the boot problem is video card related because it often stalls on the ASUS logo. I'm running Arch Linux and have had stability problems with both the Nouveau and Nvidia drivers (currently I'm running Nouveau).

Answer (score 1):

Check the capacitors (black or brown cylinders) on your motherboard. If any of them are swollen on the top or have some kind of goo coming out of theirs tops, you probably have a motherboard issue and should look into getting it replaced. Even if the capacitors seem fine, I would still recommend running some tests on your motherboard. I recently had a desktop that was stalling at the Bios/Logo screen and it was a motherboard issue. I hope this helps!

Comment: What tools do you recommend using to test the motherboard?

Comment: @ReedG.Law Check out this page for different hardware and software testers. http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001089.htm

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's the Nouveau driver. I've switched back to Nvidia and now it's stable. It seems every few years I have to switch when I encounter a problem with one driver or the other. In the past I had trouble with Firefox slowing down text entry when using Nvidia.